# How Can I Create an Application With TabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode7, uitabbar

I want a tab bar with 3 tabs.And I want to have a table view in each tab view. I have 3 table view controller and I want add those views in 3 tab.  I don't know how do it.

Comment: Hint : Check tabbar template project working . Add TableView in First view controller , do same for other view controller. After your understanding ,create third view controller,set navigation to third view and add tableview in third view .

Comment: did you research before posting? did you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Create UITabBarController and in ViewDidLoad add your tableViewControllers like this:

```
    let item1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstTableViewController") as! UITableViewController

    let item2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondTableViewController") as! UITableViewController
    let item3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thirdTableViewController")  as! UITableViewController


    let controllers = [item1,item2, item3]
    self.viewControllers = controllers
```

change identifiers and storyBoard name with your identifiers and name

Comment: i don't have storyBoard  for my tableViewControllers. i create my table view  controller programmatically.my main storyBoard  is empty.

Comment: The Its easier you create view controllers like this 
let item1 = YourTableViewController() and add them in array

Answer (score 0):

```
EmployeeViewController *evc = [[EmployeeViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:evc];
FavoriteViewController *fvc = [[FavoriteViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]`initWithRootViewController:fvc`];
 self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
NSArray* controllers2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc1,nc2, nil];
        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers2;
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```